# Java JMenuItem Show Form using CTRL+F5 not working

Tags: java

I am trying to show Form by pressing CTRL+F5 but unfortunately it is not working, but
any other key using CTRL key, for example CTRL+T or CTRL+H working fine. Please help me and let me know how to solve this problem.

[here screen shot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvPCt.png)

Comment: Edit your question and include the code that creates the JMenuItem (as text, please, not as an image).

Comment: You need to use an accelerator. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I used accelerator, but some function keys using CTRL mask are not working like CTRL+F1, CTRL+F5, CTRL+F6 and using characters with CTRL mask all keys are working fine.         I have enclosed Screen shot.